# How to send an iCalendar the same way Outlook does in .NET

Tags: .net, outlook, icalendar, mailkit, mimekit

Currently I'm able to send an email with MailKit with an ics file as attachment created with iCal.net. This works but I only get to see it as an attachment. When I create an appointment manually in Outlook I'll get the fancy UI.

[image: Outlook Example]

When I create it programmatically I'll get this.

[image]

I want to create the fancy UI programmatically. It seems it has nothing to do with the ICS because I manually created an ICS file through Outlook. And used that ics file to send through my application and still no success.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string serializedCalendar = CreateRecurringEvent();
        File.WriteAllText(@"F:\test.ics", serializedCalendar);
        SendMail();
    }

    private static void SendMail()
    {
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@tribbiani.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Monica Geller", "monica@geller.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Chandler Muriel Bing", "chandler@murielbing.com"));
        message.Subject = "How you doin?";

        var builder = new BodyBuilder
        {
            TextBody = @"<bodytext>"
        };

        builder.Attachments.Add(@"F:\test.ics");
        message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
            client.Connect("<host>", 235236);
            client.Authenticate("<username>", "<password>");
            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }

    private static string CreateRecurringEvent()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime later = now.AddHours(1);
        var rrule = new RecurrencePattern(FrequencyType.Daily, 1) { Count = 5 };

        var e = new CalendarEvent
        {
            Start = new CalDateTime(now),
            End = new CalDateTime(later),
            RecurrenceRules = new List<RecurrencePattern> { rrule }
        };

        var calendar = new Calendar();
        calendar.Events.Add(e);

        var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
        return serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can create the meeting request that will work with Outlook:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@tribbiani.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Monica Geller", "monica@geller.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Chandler Muriel Bing", "chandler@murielbing.com"));
message.Subject = "How you doin?";

var mixed = new Multipart ("mixed");
mixed.Add (new TextPart ("plain") {
    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.QuotedPrintable,
    Text = "Would you like to join this meeting?"
});

var ical = new TextPart ("calendar") {
    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
    Text = CreateRecurringEvent (),
};

ical.ContentType.Parameters.Add ("method", "REQUEST");

mixed.Add (ical);

message.Body = mixed;
```

Comment: I am not able to make this work in Outlook on Mac (haven't tested Windows). If I add as an attachment via the BodyBuilder class then the email sends as the original poster suggests. Following as it exactly shown here, there is a file attached that says "not supported calendar message.ics". The header is also output as:

`--B_3652851897_92588008
Content-type: text/calendar; name="not supported calendar message.ics";
 x-mac-creator="4F50494D"
Content-disposition: attachment;
 filename="not supported calendar message.ics"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64`

However, it functions the same

Comment: I just tested the solution and it works prefectly! Thanks so much.

Comment: @carlowahlstedt I have the same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember exactly and I no longer have access to the codebase I was using this for.